# Error running ai-generated script Converting py args to operator properties expected a float type not a tuple

Tags: scripting

I have this script but I get an error running script

`Converting py args to operator properties expected a float type not a tuple`

```
import bpy
import random

# set the dimensions of the city
num_buildings = 100
building_min_height = 10
building_max_height = 100
building_min_width = 5
building_max_width = 10

# create the buildings
for i in range(num_buildings):
    # randomize the building dimensions
    building_height = building_min_height + random.random() * (building_max_height - building_min_height)
    building_width = building_min_width + random.random() * (building_max_width - building_min_width)
    
    # create the building mesh
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
        location=(i * building_width, 0, 0),
        size=(building_width, building_height, building_width)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

if you read your "answer" of Blender in the console, it says:

[image]

so either you change it scale instead of size like so:

```
import bpy
import random

# set the dimensions of the city
num_buildings = 100
building_min_height = 10
building_max_height = 100
building_min_width = 5
building_max_width = 10

# create the buildings
for i in range(num_buildings):
    # randomize the building dimensions
    building_height = building_min_height + random.random() * (building_max_height - building_min_height)
    building_width = building_min_width + random.random() * (building_max_width - building_min_width)
    
    # create the building mesh
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
        location=(i * building_width, 0, 0),
        scale=(building_width, building_height, building_width)
    )
```

or you use a single float with parameter size instead of a tuple (but i think you don't want that)

result:

[image]

Comment: Thx for reply and help. Yes I'm only learning. I was testing openai script writing, but almost everything it does is not good at all right now.

Comment: @MikolajAlexander I think it's pretty close to generating something worthwhile. Just invert the Y and Z dimensions and you'll have a city skyline in front view. An AI doesn't know what a city should look like, after all saudis are building a linear city as we speak so... not so bad :)